# Translating “It’s not like x” and “Not that x”?

Tags: expressions, traduction

How would I say for example “I mean, it’s not like they’ll let me go”? Meaning it’s not likely they’ll let me go, realistically they won’t let me go, etc.

Also, how would I say for example “I’m glad you finished it, not that I thought you wouldn’t!”

Do these phrases have any fixed equivalents?

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with stbr's answer for the first sentence, that's how I would have said it (in case it gets deleted or edited, I copy it here):

> Je veux dire, ce n'est pas (c'est pas) comme s'ils allaient me laisser partir

For the second one I would prefer to use a slightly more elegant sentence using "Non (pas) que" and avoiding the repetition of "pas":

> Je suis heureux que tu aies fini ça, (non) (pas) que j'en doutais mais ...

Note that "non" and "pas" are between parenthesis because each could be omitted, but **not** both at the same time. Omitting one or the other changes slightly how formal the sentence is. Here's my ordering (based on my feeling) from least to most formal:

1. Pas que j'en doutais
2. Non pas que j'en doutais
3. Non que j'en doutais

Answer (score 1):

"I mean, it’s not like they’ll let me go”

> Je veux dire, ce n'est pas (c'est pas) comme s'ils allaient me laisser partir

“I’m glad you finished it, not that I thought you wouldn’t!”

> Je suis heureux que tu aies fini ça (que tu en aies fini avec ça), ce n'est pas que je n'y croyais pas (plus) mais...

That's how I would translate these sentences.

Comment: En fonction du contexte, j'aurai aussi retiré la négation du "ce n'est pas" pour laisser un "C'est pas comme s'ils allaient..."

Comment: Oui exactement @Kenichi-san enlevé le *n'* sonne plus naturel, j'ai voulu la faire plus "formel"

Answer (score 1):

“I mean, it’s not like they’ll let me go”

- Il y a peu de chances qu'on me laisse partir.
- Ça m'étonnerait qu'ils me laissent partir.

“I’m glad you finished it, not that I thought you wouldn’t!”

- Tu l'as fini, je suis content, mais j'étais sûr que t'allais y arriver.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formal way to translate the second sentence:

> Je suis content que tu aies terminé, mais loin de moi l'idée que tu aurais pu échouer.